# I'm getting a (TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object) while working with pytube library

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, pytube

**python**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from pytube import YouTube
import pytube

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def find():
    search1 = request.form.get("search")
    print(search1)
    print(type(search1))
    subt = pytube.YouTube(search1)  # <-- Error occurs in this line.
    print(subt)
    cap = subt.captions.get_by_language_code('en')
    print("Video english subtitle")
    print(cap.generate_srt_captions())
    return render_template("sub.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Error:**
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

results = regex.search(string)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: apparently your error has occurred in some other code. What is the result of `print(string)`

Comment: I have to the post request "if request.method == 'POST':"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from pytube import YouTube
import pytube

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template("sub.html")


@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def find():
    search1 = request.form.get("search")
    print(search1)
    print(type(search1))
    subt = pytube.YouTube(search1)
    cap = subt.captions.get_by_language_code('en')
    print("Video english subtitle")
    print(cap.generate_srt_captions())
    return render_template("sub.html", cap=cap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

*You can use this code to download the youtube subtitle.*